# Коррекция кода для более точной работы:

Tags: c++, visual-c++, потоки-данных, ввод

[image: Начало:]

[image: Упся:]

```
unsigned f;
cin >> f;
do
{
    if (f == 9)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = -100 + rand() % 200;
            }
        }
    }
    if (f == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                cout << "Fill arr[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
                cin >> arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if ((f != 9) && (f != 0))
    {
        cout << "Error! Try again: ";
        cin >> f;
    }
} while ((f != 9) && (f != 0));
```

Comment: И можно ещё спросить: как обезопасить программу не только от звёздочек, восклицательных знаков и т.п., а также от русских и английских букв?

Comment: опишите, что именно считаете не точной работой. Так же опишите, как вы считаете, ваш код должен отрабатывать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вместо `cin >> f`, используйте [getline](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

И соответственно, читайте в строку.

```
string f;
getline(cin, f);
do
{
    if (f == "9")
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = -100 + rand() % 200;
            }
        }
    }
    if (f == "0")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                cout << "Fill arr[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
                cin >> arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if ((f != "9") && (f != "0"))
    {
        cout << "Error! Try again: ";
        getline(cin, f);
    }
} while ((f != "9") && (f != "0"));
```

geline читает всё строку до перевода строки (нажатия enter). Сам перевод строки также вычитывает, но не сохраняет в строку. Это поведение соответствует тому, что Вы ожидаете.

Comment: Окей, спасибо большое, можно по такому же аналогу всё запихнуть в switch - case, потому что, если нажимаю *, д, f программа снова крашится. Пишет, что для swtich нужен целочисленный или перечисляемый тип.

Comment: программа крешится та, которую я подифицировал, или Вы сделали switch/case и компилятор отказывается компилировать?

Comment: Нет, ваша программа работает идеально, в будущем буду всегда использовать такой тип данных при работе с меню пользователя, спасибо вам огромное! Тут другой случай: я хочу сделать так, чтобы она не ломалась не только в заполнении массива, но также и в основной функции программы: в пользовательском меню я использовал switch - case и туда закинул функции, но все пункты case содержат цифру: 1,2,3,4,5, но если я нажму *,f,д то программа ломается. Я попытался добавить туда снова тип string, но switch () ругается.

Comment: в switch может быть только перечисляемый тип. Строка таким не является, а один символ - да. Поэтому, можно для начала просто проверять строку на длину и брать первый символ.

Comment: Всё, изменил тип на char. Очень вам благодарен!